# In python 3, how can one add an assertion about the value of particular class attributes at testing time via mocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a value that is set early on in processing a fairly complex HTTP request, and I need my unit test to assert that this value is set properly in a private attribute of a class deep in the bowels of implementation.

It seems to me that the easiest way to do this is to mock out a function in that class that is always called after that value is set, and replace it with a new function that intercepts 'self', performs the assertion, and then calls the original function. However, I have been unable to find documentation on how to get access to the original context of a mocked-out function.

Surely this is a case that people run into all the time on nontrivial projects, so what's the best practice for this kind of test?

Comment: It's hard to reconcile _"a private attribute of a class deep in the bowels of implementation"_ with _"best practice"_ - could you provide some context? Why is this necessary to test the _behaviour_?

Comment: Test that your function produces the expected *result*, not aspects of its (current) implementation.